# Spring security requires login for a URL even though it is permitted without authentication in Configure method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Boot and Spring Security. I have multiple URLs, I want some of them to be accessed with authentication and some of them to be allowed access without authentication. I have written Configure method in such a manner. But browser is redirecting me to a login page even for URL that has been allowed access without authentication. For example, I am asked for login when I try to access localhost:8080/emailExists. What could me wrong?

My Controller class :

```
@RestController
class AppController {

  @Autowired
  private ShopSearchRepository searchRepository;

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @GetMapping("/emailExists")
  public Boolean emailExists(@RequestParam String email) {
     User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
  
     if (user == null) return false;
     else return true;
  } 

  @GetMapping("/ShopsSearch")
      List<Shop> search(@RequestParam String name) {
      return searchRepository.findByName(name);
  }

}
```

My Configure method :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/ShopsSearch/").authenticated()
    .anyRequest().permitAll()
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
}
```

Comment: please update your post with your spring debug logs

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell which URL to bypass

```
 @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/emailExists").permitAll() // allow without authentication
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll() // allow without authentication
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/newuser/*").permitAll() // allow without authentication
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/master/*").permitAll() // allow without authentication
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/exploreCourse").permitAll() // allow without authentication
            .anyRequest().authenticated() //all other need auth
        }
```

Comment: I tried this but /emailExists still returns unauthorized